# Identifying stalemate in chess engine output (UCI)

Tags: engines, uci

I am using Stockfish 15.1 via UCI to analyse chess positions.

Unfortunately, the UCI documentation is a bit silent on how stalemates should be handled. As shown in the example below, it seems that stalemate results in the response "info depth 0 score cp 0".

Can I safely assume that this output only occurs in case the position is in stalemate? (E.g., my understanding is that positions that are mate will be answered by "mate 0").

Could a stalemate position provoke any other response from the engine than "info depth 0 score cp 0"?

```
Starting Stockfish analysis on fen 8/4R3/PB5k/6R1/7P/5B2/5PP1/7K b - - 0 45
Stockfish output: info string NNUE evaluation using nn-ad9b42354671.nnue enabled
Stockfish output: info depth 0 score cp 0
Stockfish output: bestmove (none)
```

Bonus question: Is there any other case where the engine responds with "bestmove (none)"? When would this be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uci protocol does not maintain the stalemate state of the position. However the engine can send this information via the `info string` command.

```
info string This position is stalemate.
```

If this engine is run in the gui, the gui may display `This position is stalemate.` to the user.

It is not safe to consider `"info depth 0 score cp 0"` as stalemate. It can be from 3-fold repetition, fifty-move draw rule or insufficient mating material.

The `"bestmove (none)"` is not according to uci protocol. The correct message should be sent as:

```
bestmove 0000
```

I tried to [maintain the uci protocol](https://github.com/fsmosca/UCIChessEngineProtocol) in github repository, to improve and clarify it.

Comment: Thank you, Ferdy. The bestmove (none) is what I am getting from Stockfish, so it is up to them to possibly change it.

Just for my understanding: 1) Can I request the info string command somehow or will the engine automatically provide it (as I understand it only in debug mode)?

2) If I see stalemate, 3-fold repetition, fifty-move draw rule, it seems that these are all draws, correct? 

3) Getting an equal position assessment at depth 0 strikes me as rather odd. When would a chess engine assess a none-draw position like this?

Comment: On "bestmove (none)", it is up to them to change it. 1) The info string command depends on the engine authors. It has to be implemented in the engine. 2) Yes